# validation.required error with Darryldecode Cart pacakge

Tags: php, laravel, validation, e-commerce, cart

Before anything else, thanks for all the awesome responses I've seen all over this webpage. It's incredible how helpfull the community can be here.

Now, I've been practicing with Laravel on a e-commerce project and when working with `darryldecode\cart` package i get a validation.required error when adding an item to the cart.

The error appears to be in the validate function of Cart.php

```
protected function validate($item)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'quantity' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
            'name' => 'required',
        );

        $validator = CartItemValidator::make($item, $rules);

         if ($validator->fails()) {
             throw new InvalidItemException($validator->messages()->first());
         }

        return $item;
    }
```

this is my logic in the controller:

```
public function add(Product $product)
    {
         \Cart::session(auth()->id())->add(array(
         'id' => uniqid($product->id),
         'name' => $product->name,
         'price' => $product->price,
         'quantity' => 1,
         'attributes' => array(),
         'associatedModel' => $product
     ));

         return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
```

and finally the view:

```
<a href="{{ route('cart.add', $product->id)}}" class="card-link">Add to cart</a>
```

found a similar thread which wasn't showing enough information so it didn't progress at all.
[Laravel 5.8 Add to Cart using darryldecode\cart\ .."validation.required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150386/laravel-5-8-add-to-cart-using-darryldecode-cart-validation-required)

Thanks in advance for all your help!!

Fernando,

Comment: Validation required should include an error on which attribute is required. Also it would be useful to know what happens with add() method, at what stage validation is triggered and what data validation is triggered on. You should also do dd($validator->messages()) and see what you get, you may have to append ->all() to get data in the error bag

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I dd the validator with ' dd($validator->messages()->all()); ' I'd get an array of: [ '0' => 'validation.required', '1' => 'validation'.required] . So I'm in the same place.

Comment: what data do you have within $item variable? I would have expected this type of a response when validation `required` was applied on an array

Answer (score 1):

be sure that parameters are not null.
'id', 'price', 'quantity', 'name'

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and found i a solution.

Its not the most clean but i commented the validation function out on vendor/darryldecode/cart/src/Darryldecode/Cart/Cart.php:709

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new InvalidItemException($validator->messages()->first());
    }
```

If you commented this out it should work.

I hope this helps u :)

Comment: This is not a solution. Never edit anything in vendor. Upgrades will break it again.